# ListView not clearing selection

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView, with following XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/tools_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sketch_background"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@color/dark_blue">
</ListView>
```

It highlights when item is chosen and highlight changes after another one is clicked. But I want to clear that selection programatically on some event (or when item is clicked again).

Now here comes the problem: none of methods i found seems to be working. I tried:

```
tools.clearChoices();
tools.clearFocus();
tools.setSelection(-1);
tools.setItemChecked(-1, true);
```

followed by updating adapter data, requesting layout etc. Only thing working is creating new adapter but it causes list to go to the top. Any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: Well, you have the `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` attribute, so you'll probably need to change it

Comment: what do you want to do? Only one selection or multiple selection listview?

Comment: @AlejandroBertinelli why would i change it? I need single choice selection, but i want to also clear that choice on some external event. But for some reason it stays marked as chosen.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems like the was only problem with position being marked all the time. Solved it with manual setting and clearing background:

```
    toolsDrawer.getChildAt(toolsDrawer.getCheckedItemPosition()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    toolsDrawer.clearChoices();
```

and deleting android:listSelector from xml.

Comment: You can try my edited answer too it is more efficient and practical solution

Comment: @propoLis, yes, thanks, i will, if i get a chance, mine is natural more of a quickfix to the problem. But for now it has to do, since i'm on a verge of a deadline ;) sorry and thanks for input.

Comment: @propoLis will definately do once i test it ;)